Where do you plug in the cord for a freestanding tub with electrical features?
I am looking to get a freestanding tub that has a feature where it does some bubbling, sort of like a jacuzzi but much less.
I noticed on page 2 of the manual they show an electrical cord. Where do contractors end up putting this in? Is it directly to a wall? It seems odd. It's not so much free standing anymore if there is a plug coming right out of it. Is this setup pretty normal, or is the electrical cord hidden in some way (possibly under something)?

There's really no answer to this. A contractor isn't going to try and hide a cord for what's essentially an appliance, like a water fountain or lamp. It would presumably plug into a typical GFCI-protected outlet in a bathroom.

I suppose the cord could run through the floor to an outlet in an exposed lower level ceiling, or to an outlet positioned under the tub. It's not clear from that document whether the cord emerges inside an area contained by the tub skirt or outside it.

Can't put the outlets under the tub because they must be accessable without tools,  in another room - fairly sure NFPA has something to say about that too.  under a false floor - perhaps.

The cord gets plugged into a dedicated GFCI. (As per electrical connection instructions on page 4)  That means there must be an outlet with  GFCI protection that does not share power with anything else in the house. If there isn't a dedicated circuit close to the tub, you will need to have an electrician install one.
It is the minimal requirement to power the devices in your tub. The Outlet would need to be on a wall close enough to be reached by the cord. Perhaps an outlet can be placed on a post closer to the tub so as not to be so obvious.
The cord can be hidden with other furnishings, like plants, baskets or other decorator items.
This should not be a big issue unless you plan on placing the tub in the middle of the bathroom.
Another alternative is to look for a tub that can be Hardwired with wiring going through the floor.

Technically the cords each need separate breakers. There are several features to this thing. One review mentioned three cords, but the document states that those for the lights and ozone feature can share an outlet. I don't take any of that to mean that the outlet(s) must actually be dedicated, but that the features draw at or near max capacity on a 15A circuit. There's probably no code or safety requirement that they be truly dedicated.

Pg. 4 of the manual, clearly states and shows in a drawing that the blower cord must be on a 120V 15 A dedicated gfci protected circuit.  Other features cannot share this outlet.

@RMDman thanks im confused are they saying there is another electrical wire for the lights?  I do not see it pictured. For clarity the model i am looking to purchase is B0101. I see it says one dedicated gfci but then it goes on to say the lights and ozone??? Not sure what that is?

The manual is not clear on what model has what features. You need to consult the manufacturer's description.  According to the manual one dedicated GFCI and one GFCI  circuit that can be shared is needed.

Sounds to me like the blower needs a dedicated GFCI circuit, and lights and ozone can share another GFCI circuit (but just with themselves, no other loads).  This design also seems pecuilar to me—looks like the cords run through the floor and have to be plugged in somewhere in the floor below, probably into an outlet covered by an access panel?

@Huesmann - that is what i am thinking too.  As I browse their site they have a section called Question and Answers and it shows a customer asking something similiar and a "tech" stating u plug it underneath.  Not sure what the hell that means but man I am rethinking buying this brand.

Plugging underneath violates code in, probably,  most parts of the western hemisphere.

@RMDman how so (other than the plug cord going through the floor)?

@Huesmann, the cord comes out from under the tub as shown in the illustration in the manual.

Yes, as I just said—the cord has to go through the floor, which I thought was verboten.  I was asking if/what other code violations there'd be.

When you say, " through the floor", do you mean the floor of the tub or the floor under the tub?
